# Неправильно геокодируется конкретный адрес

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Нужно на карте поставить метку по адресу: Иркутская область, г. Ангарск, Второй промышленный массив, 41-й квартал, строение 15 (это компания "ИЗГТ"). Но карта относит метку в другое место рядом. Другие адреса указывает точно.
Код карты:

```
   // Функция ymaps.ready() будет вызвана, когда
// загрузятся все компоненты API, а также когда будет готово DOM-дерево.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // Создание карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        // Порядок по умолчнию: «широта, долгота».
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        // от 0 (весь мир) до 19.
        zoom: 10,
        // Элементы управления
        controls: [
            
            'zoomControl', // Ползунок масштаба
            <?php /* 'rulerControl', // Линейка
            'routeButtonControl', // Панель маршрутизации
            'trafficControl', // Пробки
            'typeSelector', // Переключатель слоев карты */ ?>
            'fullscreenControl', // Полноэкранный режим

            // Поисковая строка
            new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
                options: {
                    // вид - поисковая строка
                    size: 'large',
                    // Включим возможность искать не только топонимы, но и организации.
                    provider: 'yandex#search'
                }
            })

        ]
    });

    // Строка с адресом, который необходимо геокодировать
    var address = '<?php echo get_field('map-address', 'options'); ?>';
    // Ищем координаты указанного адреса
    var geocoder = ymaps.geocode(address);
    

    // После того, как поиск вернул результат, вызывается callback-функция
    geocoder.then(
        function (res) {

            // координаты объекта
            var coordinates = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
            console.log(coordinates);

            // Добавление метки (Placemark) на карту
            var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
                coordinates, {
                    'hintContent': address,
                    'balloonContent': 'ИЗГТ'
                }, {
                    'preset': 'islands#redDotIcon'
                }
            );

            myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
            myMap.setCenter(coordinates, 5);
            myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange:true, zoomMargin:35});
            myMap.setZoom(10);
        }
    );
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        myMap.setZoom(14);
    }, 500);

}
```

Адрес заполняется со страницы опций в вордпресс. Повторяю, другие адреса определяются нормально (Например, Иркутск, Карла Маркса, 1)
Карта внизу страницы: http://izgt-wp.tw1.ru/contacts/
Если указывать точные координаты вместо адреса, происходит то же самое

Answer (score 1):

Геокодер в состоянии показать координаты только объекта из базы адресов топонимов Яндекс.

Указанный вами адрес не отмечен на карте. Он есть только в описании организации ИЗГТ. Но за поиск организации отвечает другой сервис Яндекса — [ППО](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosearch/), геокодер к этим данным доступа не имеет.

Можно реализовать добавление метки, используя поисковую строку с провайдером 'yandex#search', этот провайдер может искать организации. Или добавлять объект по координатам, как вы и предложили (но названия адреса Геокодер не вернёт). Либо воспользоваться показом [карточки конкретной организации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization.html/), что тоже доступно в API.

И в случае необходимости сохранить текущий метод всегда есть возможность на [Народной Карте](https://n.maps.yandex.ru/#!/?z=19&ll=103.979765%2C52.456306&l=nk%23map) дописать адрес для искомого дома, который будет вполне корректно находиться геокодером, как только данные будут одобрены модератором и прорастут в общедоступную карту.